# Counter-intuitive behavior when ENTER is pressed while editing in ASP.Net ListView?

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I've got a ListView and a DetailsView component on the same .ASPX page.  The DetailsView displays aggregate totals for the rows shown in the ListView.  To keep it up to date, I call DetailsView.DataBind() in ListView ItemUpdated, ItemInserted and ItemDeleted event handlers.

When ENTER is pressed in a field while editing or inserting, changes to the current row are undone and the first visible row is put in edit mode.  If I click the Update button instead of pressing ENTER, it works as expected.

I originally assumed that this behavior was just the status quo, as it occurred before I added the DataBind calls, however I noticed by accident that if the Update button was first in the row, and the cancel button was last, pressing ENTER behaved as I wanted -- it saved the changes to the current row and exited edit mode.  But that's ONLY true if my DataBind calls are not in place.

I suppose I could add a refresh button for the DetailsView, but I really can't decide which is uglier, that or having to remember to not press ENTER.

Any ideas on how to make this thing behave?

TIA,
MM

Comment: Oh almost forgot, I'm using CLR 3.5 because of hosting provider limits; can't use 4.

Comment: I see what's happening, pressing enter is 'pressing' the first button that occurs on the page.  (They are ImageButtons.)  I fixed editing by adding a button with transparent image at the top of the page, I'll post the code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that pressing ENTER 'clicks' the first button that occurs on the form.  So I created a button above the other controls with a transparent image, and the following click handler:

```
protected void TransparentUpdateButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.EditItem != null)
    {
        ListView1.UpdateItem(ListView1.EditIndex, false);
        return;  // must return, InsertItem is always non-null
    }
    if (ListView1.InsertItem != null) // probably an unnecessary test
        ListView1.InsertNewItem(false);
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution in the universe, but seems to work, and surely beats all hell out of the way it behaves by default.  Maybe if I hadn't have used ImageButtons this wouldn't have been necessary, but the functions save, edit, delete, undo and insert are sooo easily represented by 16x16 images, the text equivilents are a waste of horizontal space.

In any case, I'll take it.  :-)